# JavaScript - Search pattern in string

Tags: javascript, regex

hello I would like to know what is the best way to search pattern like 
`AB` where  `A` should be any except `A` and `B` should only be `B` ? Exempple : '`ADSDFSDAB'` should return `false` where as `'BBBSDSSDSDNSSS'` should return true.

So, for every `B` in my string, I want to return `true` if there is no `A` preceding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where  A should be any except A...

So that's `[^A]`

> and B should only be B

And that's `B`.

So:

```
if (/[^A]B/.test(str))) {
    // Yes, it has a match
} else {
    // No, it doesn't
}
```

Live Example:

```js
test("ADSDFSDAB", false);
test("BBBSDSSDSDNSSS", true);

function test(str, expect) {
  var result = /[^A]B/.test(str);
  var good = !result == !expect;
  console.log("'" + str + "': " + result + (good ? " - Pass" : " - FAIL"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to match `B` not followed by `A`. You can use a patter like:

```
[^A]B
```

however, I'd suggest that you search for the existence of the substring `AB` in your original string and check the result.

```
originalString.indexOf('AB') !== -1
```

Comment: `[^A]B` doesn't match a B at the start of the string. Searching AB with `indexOf` is indeed the best way.